# Mean field critical exponent

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

My notes (Gould and Tobochnik) come to the conclusion that the mean field critical exponent $\beta$ is 0.5 which is larger than the experimental value (in 3 dimensions) 0.3 so that:

$$m_{mean} = \left(\frac{T_c-T}{T_c}\right)^{0.5} < \left(\frac{T_c-T}{T_c}\right)^{0.3} = m_{experiment}$$

Is there any intuition behind that result ?

**My train of thought**

I would guess that the mean field approach makes it so that the system is more likely to be magnetized since the interactions are no longer local. 
(Indeed a spin flip at any place will influence the effective field at any other place)

But this contradicts the result that is obtained in G&T so that I must be overlooking something...

ps: most articles just derive this without any interpretation which makes me think that it might not be that easy...

Comment: I don't understand your inequality. What is $T_c$ in each case, according to you? I ask this because the experimental critical temperature and the mean field critical temperature are different.

Comment: To complement the previous comment, it is well known that the mean-field magnetization is always an upper bound for the actual magnetization of the Ising model. See, for example, Section 3.10.2 in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html).

Comment: $T_c$ is the mean field critical temperature. 
And @YvanVelenik, that is indeed what my intuition would tell me but Gould and Tobochnik seems to contradict this.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. As pointed out in the first comment, the values of $T_c$ are not the same: the value of $T_c$ predicted by the mean-field approximation is always larger than the real one. (Also, note that these exponents do not correspond to a divergence, but to the rate at which the magnetization vanishes.)

Comment: Namely, the graph of the magnetization in the mean-field approximation is always above the one corresponding to the real magnetization. This clearly does not prevent the latter to vanish at a faster rate than the former...

Comment: Ah I understand now !
I should have compared $(T_{c\ mean\ field}-T)^{0.5}$ with $(T_{c\ experiment}-T)^{0.3}$ and then I would see that the mean field approximation does indeed overestimate the magnetization ?

Is this correct.

Bottom line (as you said) the critical exponents are only a relevant measure of the vanishing of the magnetization not its absolute value.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.